# how to generate a map of instructions when compiling?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

when compiling a program with gcc or any other compiler, can I somehow make the compiler generate a map of instructions in memory ??

something like:

```
0000: First Instruction
0001: Second Instruction
1000: Third Instruction (after a jump for example)
```

I would like to use these addresses as a pattern to test a design of an instruction cache. I don't care what instructions are compiled or anything like that, just the addresses of these instruction. is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way has to be to use `objdump` on your compiled output. For instance:

```
$ objdump -d /tmp/test

/tmp/test:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400410 <_start>:
  400410:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400412:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400415:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  400416:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400419:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40041d:       50                      push   %rax
  40041e:       54                      push   %rsp
  40041f:       49 c7 c0 b0 05 40 00    mov    $0x4005b0,%r8
  400426:       48 c7 c1 20 05 40 00    mov    $0x400520,%rcx
  40042d:       48 c7 c7 fa 04 40 00    mov    $0x4004fa,%rdi
  400434:       e8 b7 ff ff ff          callq  4003f0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  400439:       f4                      hlt    
  40043a:       66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

And so on. If you want to only have the addresses, just filter them out with `sed` or something.

Comment: Sorry, But what is SED ??